# (JAVASCRIPT) Como estilizar o layout desse código JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Tenho este código em javascript e gostaria de editar o layout dele, porém não sei como fazer (ou não lembro) se poderem me ajudar mostrando exemplos agradeceria.

```html
<script>
    function lastModified() {
    var modiDate = new Date(document.lastModified);
    var showAs = modiDate.getDate() + "-" + (modiDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + modiDate.getFullYear();
    return showAs
}

function GetTime() {
    var modiDate = new Date();
    var Seconds

    if (modiDate.getSeconds() < 10) {
        Seconds = "0" + modiDate.getSeconds();
    } else {
        Seconds = modiDate.getSeconds();
    }

    var modiDate = new Date();
    var CurTime = modiDate.getHours() + ":" + modiDate.getFullMinutes() + ":" + Seconds
    return CurTime
    }
    Date.prototype.getFullMinutes = function () {
        if (this.getMinutes() < 10) {
            return '0' + this.getMinutes();
        }
        return this.getMinutes();
    };

document.write("Ultima Atualização em: ")
document.write(lastModified() + " as " + GetTime());
document.write(" por ")
document.write("@ViewBag.usuarioLogado");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunca é uma boa ideia ficar adicionando conteúdo em sua tela através do `document.write()` assim como compor seu conteúdo através de concatenação, quando poderia estar usando a interpolação.

Nesse caso o ideal seria você deixar um elemento no html, para funcionar como container ou placeholder desse conteúdo e alterá-lo no carregamento da página.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let elemento = document.getElementById("mensagemAtualizacao");
  mostrarUltimaAtualizacao(elemento);
}

function mostrarUltimaAtualizacao(el) {
  let usuarioLogado = '@ViewBag.usuarioLogado';
  let mensagem = `Última Atualização em: <b>${lastModified()}</b> às <b>${GetTime()}</b>, por <b>${usuarioLogado}</b>.`;
  el.innerHTML = mensagem;
  
}

function lastModified() {
  var modiDate = new Date(document.lastModified);
  var showAs = modiDate.getDate() + "-" + (modiDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + modiDate.getFullYear();
  return showAs
}

function GetTime() {
  var modiDate = new Date();
  var Seconds

  if (modiDate.getSeconds() < 10) {
    Seconds = "0" + modiDate.getSeconds();
  } else {
    Seconds = modiDate.getSeconds();
  }

  var modiDate = new Date();
  var CurTime = modiDate.getHours() + ":" + modiDate.getFullMinutes() + ":" + Seconds
  return CurTime
}
Date.prototype.getFullMinutes = function() {
  if (this.getMinutes() < 10) {
    return '0' + this.getMinutes();
  }
  return this.getMinutes();
};
```

```html
<p id="mensagemAtualizacao">teste</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode inserir tags html no script tranquilamente, porém não é o ideal por padrões de programação (prejudica a manutenção)... a não ser que seja realmente necessário em relação ao escopo.

Eu coloquei somente a abertura de uma div com um background-color vermelho e um br apara quebra de linha, pois fechei a div no final, mas pode ser acrescentado o que for necessário, tanto html quanto css, porém, fica bagunçado!!

```html
<script>
    function lastModified() {
    var modiDate = new Date(document.lastModified);
    var showAs = modiDate.getDate() + "-" + (modiDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + modiDate.getFullYear();
    return showAs
}

function GetTime() {
    var modiDate = new Date();
    var Seconds

    if (modiDate.getSeconds() < 10) {
        Seconds = "0" + modiDate.getSeconds();
    } else {
        Seconds = modiDate.getSeconds();
    }

    var modiDate = new Date();
    var CurTime = modiDate.getHours() + ":" + modiDate.getFullMinutes() + ":" + Seconds
    return CurTime
    }
    Date.prototype.getFullMinutes = function () {
        if (this.getMinutes() < 10) {
            return '0' + this.getMinutes();
        }
        return this.getMinutes();
    };

document.write("<div style='background-color: red'>Ultima Atualização em: ")
document.write(lastModified() + " as " + GetTime());
document.write(" por <br> ")
document.write("@ViewBag.usuarioLogado</div>");
</script>
```